# Query graph db for two values belonging to same type of vertex

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I want to query in Amazon Neptune graph db two values belonging to same type of vertex. How can I achieve this in Gremlin ?

e.g.

If we write a query in sql it would look like this -

```
select * from table where id in ('ID1', 'Id2')
```

```
%%gremlin explain

g.V().has('Parts', '~id', 'ABCD')
.has('Parts', '~id', 'PQRS').values()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the SQL example, the equivalent Gremlin would be:

```
g.V().has('Parts', '~id',within( 'ABCD','PQRS')).values()
```

However, if `~Id` is the actual vertex ID, then you can just do:

```
g.V().has('Parts', id, within( 'ABCD','PQRS')).values()
```

but given an ID is unique, you don't need to check the label if you know it should be of that type:

```
g.V().hasId('ABCD','PQRS').values()
```

or even just

```
g.V('ABCD','PQRS').values()
```

Comment: This helps, I have one more question -

Comment: what if I have to find only common friend for two or more users in a way that both them have same friend. 

g.V().has('users','id', within('A', 'B')).out('friend_with').values()

This query will give back all friends that are associated with A or B. However, how can I get friends that are associated with A & B.

Comment: That's really a whole new question. I'm happy to answer it, but it would be simpler to ask it as a separate post and accept the answer to this one if possible. There are several ways to achieve the common friends pattern.